# What happens if the sub-query on an IN operator fails?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, in-operator

I have a T-SQL query where I am using the IN operator to find all records where the GUID is in the result of the subquery. However, I recently made changes to the schema so that Table6 does not have a GUID field and now has an AlternateID field. So the subquery for the IN operator fails if you run it. However, if I execute the query as a whole, it always returns all records in TableGUIDResolving table. It's almost as if the IN operator is returning TRUE for all records because the subquery is failing.

I have tried fixing the subquery, and it executes as expected when I do this.

Can someone help me explain this? Is this behavior intentional?

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableGUIDResolving 
WHERE GUID IN (SELECT AlternateID AS GUID FROM Table1
               UNION
               SELECT GUID FROM Table2
               UNION
               SELECT GUID FROM Table3
               UNION
               SELECT GUID FROM Table4
               UNION
               SELECT GUID FROM Table5
               UNION
               SELECT GUID FROM Table6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.  That is what happens when you use subqueries without qualified column names.  You think you are saying:

```
select table6.GUID from table6
```

but this doesn't exist, so the scoping rules in SQL change it to:

```
select TableGUIDResolving.GUID from table6
```

I would recommend that you change your logic to a series of `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TableGUIDResolving tgr WHERE GUID IN (
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.AlternateID = tgr.GUID) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.GUID = tgr.GUID) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table3 t3 WHERE t3.GUID = tgr.GUID) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table4 t4 WHERE t4.GUID = tgr.GUID) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table4 t5 WHERE t5.GUID = tgr.GUID) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table4 t6 WHERE t6.GUID = tgr.GUID)
```

If you have an index on `GUID`/`AlternateID` in each of the tables, then this should have much better performance.

Comment: If this is the case, why doesn't it complain if, for example, table2 has a guid column?

Comment: @Andrew . . . If it finds the column in the table(s) referenced in the subquery, then it uses the column there.  If not, it looks in an outer scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was hard to find an answer to this on the internet because the word "IN" doesn't search well.